# python sql modulo inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7

I need some help writing to a postgres sql table with python.

First column **id** is an `int`, second column **day** is a `float`. How do I properly format it? This does not work.

When I do `values('%d');'''%id)` it works but I cannot figure out how to insert `int` and `float` in the same line

```
cur.execute('''insert into test (id, long) values('%d %d');''' % (id, long))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%s` and let Psycopg do the type adapting:

```
cur.execute('''insert into test (id, long) values (%s, %s);''', (id, long))
```